# How to get current record from start date to nth month using mysql

Tags: mysql

[image]

Hi Guys i want to get current record from this scenario like start date 10-03-2018 to 11 months then last date is 10-02-2019 from this duration.

Comment: try this finction $date = date("YYYY-MM-DD"); this will give you current date and perform increment to fetch last date

Comment: i want to get current record like today date is 11-03-2017 so the record will come first record where id is 7 so please suggest me it's which query is suitable for this scenario

Comment: this function will give toy today's date i always use this to get current date

Comment: you have to just change date formate in which you want the date

Comment: ya i know you are right but please suggest me mysql query which is better for this scenario

Comment: ok  you want records from today to 11 months after, right?

Comment: ya but 11 not a fixed value it will be changed like 5, 4

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `extend_blog_details` as ExtendBlogDetail WHERE item_id='$item_id' and CURDATE() between start_date and DATE_ADD(start_date,INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,NOW(),DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL `number_of_months` month)) month) limit 1
```

i have got the current record from this query

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php
$date = date('Y-m-d'); //2017-03-14
$finaldate= date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+11 months", strtotime($date)));
$select_query = "SELECT * 
FROM tablename
WHERE date >  '".$finaldate."'";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is your sql query for mysql :

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 11 MONTH)
```

change your table name and column name according to your database

you can make changes according to you like month, year or day

Comment: no record found and we can not fixed the months like 11 it will be changed accordingly user

Comment: can you provide your code so i can fix it? because if it is entered by user then we have to use variable

Comment: i am explain you again briefly. I have a Blog table where user can add your blog post duration like i want to post today to 5 months after 5 months user want to extend your blog  so the records i have manged i this table the item_id is a blog id

Comment: the Scenario is  like i have post the blog date is 10-03-2017 and end date is 10-06-2017 it is 3 months duration blog and user will extend this duration in 10-04-2017 and duration is 10-07-2017 to 10-10-2017 so how can get current duration. from today date the current duration is 10-03-2016 to 10-06-2017 can you understand my query

Comment: ya i got you but you have code for this or you directly enter your data to the database?

Comment: ya i have code but i want only query 

  ` public static function getCurrentEditionDetail($product_id)
    {

       return $getBlogDuration=ClassRegistry::init('ExtendBlogDetail')->find('first',array('conditions'=>array('ExtendBlogDetail.item_id'=>$product_id),'order'=>array('ExtendBlogDetail.id'=>'desc'),'recursive'=>-1,'limit'=>1, 'offset'=>1));

    }`

See this code

Comment: have you understand

Comment: nope, i can't get your point if i can see some code or some thing then i will get :(

Comment: <code>public static function getCurrentEditionDetail($product_id)
    {

       return $getBlogDuration=ClassRegistry::init('ExtendBlogDetail')->find('first',array('conditions'=>array('ExtendBlogDetail.item_id'=>$product_id),'order'=>array('ExtendBlogDetail.id'=>'desc'),'recursive'=>-1,'limit'=>1, 'offset'=>1));

    } 

$product_id=198

Comment: which platform and server you are using?

Comment: I have used cakephp and apache server

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with another way for example,

```
$startdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$your_date);
SELECT date,start_date,CONCAT('INTERVAL ',number_of_months,' ','MONTH') as comapre_date FROM table_name having date BETWEEN start_date AND (start_date - comapre_date)
```

Try using this query hope this will work..

Comment: `SELECT start_date,CONCAT('INTERVAL ',number_of_months,' ','MONTH') as comapre_date FROM extend_blog_details having start_date BETWEEN '2017-03-11' AND ('2017-03-11' - comapre_date)`

You are saying this right

Comment: Hi Khushi

`SELECT start_date,CONCAT('INTERVAL ',number_of_months,' ','MONTH') as comapre_date FROM extend_blog_details having start_date BETWEEN start_date AND (start_date - comapre_date)`

It's too near I have used this query but it's gave me all of records can you help me where i have modified so this give me correct result

Comment: and in this query i can't use where clause

Comment: you can not use 'comapre_date' in where clause.
Can you check that  (start_date - compare_date) returns correct value?